# Ansible global vars.yml loop Task in Template

Tags: python, ansible

How do I loop variables in Ansible into a template to create multiple virtual hosts? (*Note: The Ansible docs are down for me*).

If I move all my variables into the playbook it kind of defeats the purpose of de-coupling.

However, if I must do the above I am still not sure how I can apply `dict[key].value` to the `with_items` loop into a template. Here is my source:

**/vars.yml**

```
apache_vhosts:
  happy:
    ssl: true
    server_name: happy.com
    directory_name: happy
  pappy:
    ssl: false
    server_name: pappy.com
    directory_name: pappy
```

**/roles/apache2/tasks/main.yml**

```
- name: make projects vhost
  template: src=projects.conf.j2
            dest=/etc/apache2/sites-available/projects.conf
            owner=root
            group=root
  with_items:
    apache_vhosts
```

**/roles/apache2/templates/vhost.j2**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot {{ apache_vhost_folder }}/{{ directory_name}}
    ...
```

I am not sure how this works. I have a `dict` rather than a `list` (If I could make a list it might be easier), but I am also unsure of how I would get the `index` within the `dict` or `list`.

Any advise would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a loop (`with_items`) every item will be available as `item`. This also will be available inside your template. You then can access it like this:

```
{{ item["directory_name"] }}
```